# What's the meaning of "to reach opinion leaders"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "to reach opinion leaders" in the [following text](http://www.indepthnews.info/index.php/global-issues/1860-challenges-remain-but-good-news-for-nuclear-disarmament)?

> He called for concerted efforts *to reach opinion leaders* and
>   policymakers in the nuclear weapons states: “Many of them have already
>   acknowledged the essential bankruptcy of deterrence doctrine in a
>   world where non-state actors are seeking access to nuclear weapons
>   technology and stated that a nuclear weapon-free world will be a safer
>   world.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion leaders are people with an active voice in a community.They are influential members of a community, group, or society to whom others turn for advice, opinions, and views.These are the people who shape opinions on things in a community or society, something akin to intellectual trendsetters.

Hence the author talks about reaching out to active voices in the community so that public opinion can be shaped through them.

Answer (score 0):

It means to persuade those who influence the views of others to be sympathetic to a particular approach.